# Are harmonics always the peaks in the frequency response plot?

Tags: frequency-response, harmonics

I would like to implement a certain type of audio alarm with 1 fundamental frequency and 4 harmonics.

The example frequency response of a qualified alarm on the spectrum analyzer is shown in the picture below:

[image]

I note that the fundamental frequency (aka 1st harmonic) and harmonic frequencies are all outstanding peaks in the plot.

Is that always true？Even so, how can we tell that those peaks are for sure harmonic frequencies instead of noise?

Comment: Do you know what the fundamental frequency is *a priori*, or do you have to measure it? What is the source of the signal?

Comment: If you look at the waveform (as on an oscilloscope) in **volts** vs. **time** format, the waveform shape will be unchanging if all the frequency components are harmonically-related. If one or more are *not harmonically-related*, the waveform shape will change with time.

Comment: Instead of showing the frequency plot of a severely distorted waveform with its harmonics exact multiples of the fundamental frequency, you are showing 5 or more frequency tones that are added together.

Answer (score 2):

Q: Are harmonics always peaks in the spectral plot?

A: No.  They may not rise above noise

Q: Are peaks in the spectral plot always harmonics?

A: No.  Peaks in the spectral plot indicate tones, or at least narrowband signals

Q: Can peaks in the spectral plot be noise?

A: Yes.

What's missing from your question, is what makes harmonics harmonics -- that spectral plot shows peaks that are not all at multiples of 770Hz, and are thus not harmonics.  Those peaks would be more properly called overtones -- but I don't know if they're intended as such, or if the plot is in error somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, peaks in the signal spectrum indicate relatively pure tonal components in the signal.

For example if you are measuring sound, then a musical instrument playing a single note will produce a spectrum with strong peaks at the fundamental frequency associated with that note, and at harmonics of that fundamental. But if you play a chord, then you will get peaks at multiple anharmonic frequencies corresponding to the different notes in the chord, and at harmonics of all of those tones.

If you have noise (or interference) that might be confused with tones you want to measure or their harmonics, then you will want to fix that before trying to measure your desired signal. That would be like trying to listen to a concert while your 10-year-old plays the recorder in the seat next to you.

Answer (score 0):

It's a tone. Every instrument produces a fundamental frequency and harmonics. Instruments differ by producing different harmonics and their amplitudes.

If you want to hear, how the sound of your tone sounds like, visit [this site](https://meettechniek.info/additional/additive-synthesis.html)

[image]

I have entered the fundamental 770 Hz (H1) and 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th harmonics.

> Is that always true？Even so, how can we tell that those peaks are for
> sure harmonic frequencies instead of noise?

Because their amplitude is much higher than the noise.

Also what you call it noise, could be also an artifact of windowing when doing FFT - it may not be really present in the signal.